# Continuity of a Function expressed as an Infinite Sum

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Here's a function that appeared in my undergraduate level analysis course -
while I do understand how the integrals have been computed and why they're 1 and 0 respectively, I am not able to make any substantial comment on the **continuity** of the function $f$.

The lecture slide, however, mentions that f is continuous everywhere in its domain except at $(1,1)$. I attach a screenshot of the same (pardon me for not using LaTeX this time, I've exams going on and I'm really in a hurry)

[image]

Could someone please help me out here? How should I start investigating the continuity of $f$? The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition seems like bit too much for this, is there an easier way out? Please point me in the right direction, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(x,y)\neq (1,1)$, then there exists $N$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $(x,y)$ such that $(g_n(s)-g_{n+1}(s))g_n(t)=0$ for all $n>N$ and all $(s,t)\in U$ (if $x\neq 1$ then we take a neighborhood such that $g_n(s)$ and $g_{n+1}(s)$ will be $0$ and if $y\neq 1$ we take a neighborhood such that $g_n(t)$ will be $0$).  So, $f|_U$ is just a finite sum of continuous functions and therefore is continuous.  Since $U$ is an open neighborhood of $(x,y)$ this means $f$ is continuous at $(x,y)$.

Comment: What does the notation $f|_U$ stand for?

Comment: That just means $f$ with its domain restricted to $U$.